# Vuex get new value inside the method after change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I can't get the new value from vuex (i'm new on vue)

```
this.$store.dispatch('updateSelectedDate', {data: this.selectedDay})
console.log(this.$store.state.day)
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: How does the `updateSelectedDate` action update the `state`? Without seeing that code it's difficult to speculate what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a computed property in order to return state value :

```
computed:{
   day(){
    return this.$store.state.day
 }
}
```

and call it like :

```
this.$store.dispatch('updateSelectedDate', {data: this.selectedDay})
console.log(this.day)
```

Comment: Could you include an explanation of why this works because it looks functionally equivalent to the code in the question to me?